# In Liferay 7.x, how can we have in a single module more portlets and for each of them a different Language.properties?

Tags: internationalization, liferay

I created a `mvc-portlet` module in Liferay 7.x, that has 2 portlets, test and test2. Each portlet has its own `Language.porperties`. Each property is its subfolder

```
resources/content/test/Language.properties
```

and

```
resources/content/test2/Language.properties.
```

In the portlet compoent properties I have

```
"javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.test.Language"
```

and

```
"javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.test2.Language"
```

but the default values (for the `mvc-portlet` template) for the keys won’t load. What am I doing wrong here?

You can find some sample code here: https://github.com/charalamposc/liferay-literals

Comment: In the portlet I can use the following code, and then it will work:                 `ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundleUtil.getBundle("content.test.Language", themeDisplay.getLocale(), this.getClass());`
`_log.info("test.caption:" + LanguageUtil.get(resourceBundle, "test.caption"));`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're splitting up the resources this way? Modules are cheap, so you could just deploy two different bundles - problem solved, and they can even be deployed independent of each other. If there's common code between the two, make it a third module. On the other hand: I'd assume if it's ok to have two portlets in a single bundle, they're small enough that the resource bundle(s) will be small as well, thus the price to combine them will be low. Also: Less surprise for future maintainers (might be yourself) when they find a seemingly incomplete resource bundle

Comment: Yeah, you ' ve right. But the code was from 6.2 and was part of a conversion. I wanted to keep the code in the same form like in the 6.2 plugin. After I saw that it wasn' t possible to load the resource, I wanted to find out a way to solve it, like a puzzle. It is strange that we have a property like "javax.portlet.resource-bundle", but we can' t give any other value that "content.Language". It should be hard coded, not a property.

Comment: I agree: My expectation would be that a configured property actually is honored. Might be a bug, or a misunderstanding on either side. But in general, for maintainability, I'd not attempt to use that feature anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution (don’t know if it's the best - but it works). I implemented two resource bundle loaders (https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029317371-Resource-Bundle-Override), one for every resource. It seems, it adds an additional resource bundle to the module components.